# Correct payload for TensorFlow Serving REST API

Tags: rest, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I have converted a Keras model to a Tensorflow estimator, added Tensorflow Transform to the graph and then exported the model for serving.

When I check the model signature, I can see the following info:

```
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['examples'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: input_example_tensor:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['specialities'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 154)
        name: specialities/Softmax:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I converted the feature specifications with `tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn` therefore the name of the input node in the signature is `example`. The name of the input node in my model is `procedures`.

I then use `saved_model_cli` to manually test the exported model and everything looks good (I got a list of probabilities)

```
!saved_model_cli run --dir=/model_dir/1533849825 
                     --tag_set serve 
                     --signature_def serving_default  
                     --input_examples 'examples=[{"procedures": ["99214,17000,17000,13121,99203"]}]'
```

Now, I load this model into TF Serving, the model server starts up ok.

When I request a model prediction with the json payload below (application/json), I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "signature_name":"serving_default",
  "instances":[
    {
       "examples":["99214,17000,17000,13121,99203"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Error:

```
"error": "Expected serialized to be a vector, got shape: [1,1]
```

A different payload structure, leads to this error

```
{
 "signature_name":"serving_default",
 "examples":[
    {
      "procedure":["99214,17000,17000,13121,99203"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Error:

```
"error": "JSON Value: {\n    \"signature_name\": \"serving_default\",\n    
\"examples\": [\n        {\n            \"procedures\": 
["99214,17000,17000,13121,99203"]]\n        }\n    ]\n} not formatted 
correctly. Expecting object with \'instances\' key and a list/array as the value."
```

**What is the correct payload format for the TensorFlow Serving request in this prediction case?**

Does the payload need to be formatted in the tf.Example structure?

Comment: Did you try using the `raw_input_receiver_fn' instead? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn

Comment: See also here https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/api_rest#encoding_binary_values

Answer (score 2):

I give an example here with `Estimator` api, hope it can help someone who come up with the similar problems.

To export a `SavedModel` with `Estimator` you need a `input_receiver_fn` to accpect inputs when serving. The `input_receiver_fn` in my application is as following:

```py
def _serving_input_receiver_fn():
  serialized_tf_sample = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string,
                                        shape=None, name='input_example_tensor')
  receiver_tensors = {'example': serialized_tf_sample}
  # example_proto: {'feature_name': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),}
  features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_sample, example_proto)
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)
```

You can put the following code under `train_and_evaluate` to export a `SavedModel`

```
estimator.export_savedmodel(model_export_path, _serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

To serve the model you can pull the `tensorflow/serving` docker image, you can refer https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker for help. (I suggest you pull the image with devel tag, since it's better to debug)

Simply run the below command to start serving

`/usr/local/bin/tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501 --model_name=my_model --model_base_path my_model_path`

The client code is simple, but should take care of. Because the serialized example should be encoded with base64 and added a `b64` key.

```py
import requests
resp = requests.post('http://host:8501/v1/models/my_model:predict', json={
        'instances': [
            {'example': {'b64':base64.b64encode(single_example.SerializeToString())}}
        ]})
resp.json()
```

If you have any question, just comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try exporting your model using [build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/estimator/export/export.py#L317) instead? And pass the raw tensor (`procedure`) in JSON predict request as:

```
{
 "signature_name": "serving_default",
 "instances": [
    {
      "procedure": ["99214,17000,17000,13121,99203"]
    }
  ]
}
```

given that you are using default serving signature name and single named input you can shorten the request to:

```
{ 
  "instances": ["99214,17000,17000,13121,99203"]
}
```

Regarding your existing code, exporting model using `build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn()` requires serialized `tf.Example` string blob as input. `saved_model_cli` tool (being python and having access to protos) does this serialization for you and hence works well. Doing proto serialization while using Web/REST APIs can get cumbersome (requires protobuf libs), and is an overkill for your usage.

Answer (score 0):

As netfs above said, it is cumbersome to use `build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn()` for REST APIs. To elaborate how cumbersome it is, here is the answer to your original question, the POST body should be something like:

```
{
  "signature_name":"serving_default",
  "instances":[
    {
       "examples":{"b64": base64.b64encode(example.SerializeToString()).decode('utf-8')}
    }
  ]
}
```

The `example` is a tf.Example proto object. For instance:

```
example = tf.train.Example(
            features=tf.train.Features(
              feature={"procedures": 
                          tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[99214,17000,17000,13121,99203]))
                )
            )
```